# get all images that belong to a specific gallery

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get all images that belong to a specific gallery. These images have to be selected from Image class.

this is relationship, inside Image class:

```
public function galleries()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Gallery::class, 'gallery_image');
}
```

and inside Gallery:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class, 'gallery_image', 'gallery_id', 'image_id')->withPivot('order');
}
```

I have tried this:

```
$images = Image::with(array(
    'galleries' => function ($query) use($search)
    {
        $query->where('slug', $search);
    }->paginate()
```

but it still returns all images back even when I send it specific gallery.

Can anyone help me with this query?

It must be done with Image:: and not Gallery:: I must select images through image class and not Gallery class because of a specific way I am doing this. So I need help with above query and not a suggestion to go with Gallery::some_query_here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `whereHas`:

```
$images = Image::with('galleries')
    ->whereHas('galleries', function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('slug', $search);
    })
    ->paginate();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is the correct answer to the question, whereHas, I knew about it but I forgot about it, thanks for giving me the correct query :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to get the gallery first and then get its images:

```
$gallery = Gallery::with('images')->whereSlug($slug)->first();
$images = $gallery->images;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I specifically told at the end of my question I can't do it like that

Comment: @maxit, why can't you do it this way? What your trying to do is filter the galleries of all the images, not the other way around.

Comment: I am trying to filter images not galleries, images can be filtered on a number of different things.